# Importar projeto do eclipse para a mais recente API do Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Fiz o import do projeto de um aplicativo do eclipse para o Android Studio. A importação ocorreu sem problemas e o gradle foi criado. Porém, percebo que os componentes visuais como EditText, ProgressBar, AppBar, Button estão com um visual defasado, da versão 3.0 do android. Atualizei o meu minSdk para 15 e targetSdk para 23 e atualizei o gradle, porém os componentes visuais continuam nas APIs antigas.

Percebo também que sempre que crio uma nova activity, tenho o seguinte padrão:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TesteActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste);
    }
}
```

As **activitys** herdam apenas de **activity**, e não de **AppCompatActivity**, como visto abaixo em qualquer projeto criado no Android Studio:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Ao alterar a herança da `TesteActivity` de `Activity` para `AppCompatActivity`, o Android não reconhece a classe. Lembrando que este problema ocorre apenas dentro do projeto importado do eclipse.

Existe alguma forma de fazer o import deste projeto antigo, para trabalhar com os componentes/recursos mais modernos do Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa, consegui encontrar onde estava o problema.

A classe `AppCompatActivity` só está disponível à partir do sdk tools 22, e meu projeto estava usando o 21. Sendo assim, atualizei o sdk tools do meu build.gradle (Module:app) e reiniciei o Android Studio, ficando da seguinte forma.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.spinsuite.base"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

Depois disso, fui no menu Build/Rebuild project. Fazendo isso, basta importar `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` na classe desejada e extender de `extends AppCompatActivity`. Estou tendo alguns problemas de crash durante a execucação da aplicação, porém no projeto está tudo ok. Acredito que este erro seja assunto para outro tópico.

Pergunta relacionadas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084808/if-i-use-new-v7-appcompat-library-do-i-still-need-v4-support-library-fo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803405/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity-support-v7-libraries-arent-recognized
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947794/cant-resolve-appcompatactivity

Answer (score 6):

Experimente colocar

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

Em "dependencies" no ficheiro build.gradle

Comment: Mesmo colocando isso nas dependencies, continua com a mensagem de Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity' ao herdar a classe. Ao dar o run no gradle para atualizar, é exibido o erro: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'spinsuite-brerp'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@3ad836c1.

Comment: Veja qual versão você usa, normalmente eh a mesma que o buildTools. 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:(Sua versão)'

Answer (score 1):

Mude manualmente o código para herdar de AppCompatActivity.

Acerca dos widgets(EditText, Button, etc), verifique o seu ficheiro styles.xml .. Veja qual é o tema definido. Procure usar algum tema que herde de Material.Theme

Comment: Quando altero o código da classe para herdar de AppCompatActivity ela não é reconhecida, fica como se a classe AppCompatActivity não existisse.

Comment: Sobre o tema, já tentei mudar e da crash na aplicação quando faço isso, infelizmente não salvei o log de erros.O pior é que mesmo quando eu voltei para o theme antigo, o app continuou crashando ao ser aberto, precisar clonar o repositório novamente.